# Cannot understand why gameState is not changing in-game

Tags: lua, cs50, love2d

I'm a beginner at coding and I am currently doing GD50 by Harvard. I cannot figure out what is wrong with my code here. What i'm trying to do is update the game state when enter is pressed. I implemented a basic menu where if you press one, you are sent to the start state, which is working fine, but i can't figure out how to combine this with pressing a different key to actually start the game(updating to serve state and so on). Hope i was clear with the explanation. Any help would be appreciated. Here's my code(pls say if i need to post more):

```
function love.keypressed(key)
    if key == 'escape' then
        love.event.quit()

    elseif key == 'm' then 
        gameState = 'menu'

    elseif key == '1' then
        if gameState == 'menu' then 
            gameState = 'start'
        end

    elseif key == 'enter' then
        if gameState == 'start' then
            gameState = 'serve'
        elseif gameState == 'serve' then
            gameState = 'play'
        elseif gameState == 'done' then
            gameState = 'serve'

            ball:reset()
        
            player1Score = 0
            player2Score = 0
        
            if winningPlayer == 1 then
                servingPlayer = 2
            else
                servingPlayer = 1
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure its entirely clear what the problem is (nothing jumps out as strictly incorrect in this code). Consider creating a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), with the bare minimum code required to replicate the issue. For example, there could be something wrong with your `update` function with interferes with the logic in this function (I'm thinking a typo like `gameState = 'strat'`, or the like).

Comment: You may want to consider inverting the logic here. Instead of handling keypresses individually, make it so that game states handle input separately (by passing input to the "active state"), and are responsible for requesting a change of state from some controlling entity (this is more or less the basis for a [FSM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine)).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.